# Can Someone help me write a query to determine which team lost a match AND a separate query to count each teams losses

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have tried the following code.

```
SELECT  (Team 1) OR ( Team 2) AS[Losser], Winner
FROM MatchesTbl
WHERE (WINNER NOT LIKE (Team 1))
```

I have attached an image of the table I am working with. I am working in Microsoft access.
I am still very new to programming and I am trying to do this for a school project.

[image: Image of Table being used]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use MS Access you can use the [IIF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3) function to get the first result

```
SELECT T.Team1, T.Team2, T.Winner, IIf([Team1]=[Winner],[Team2],[Team1]) AS Loser
FROM tblMatches AS T;
```

Please note that I modified your orignal table name and field names a little bit.

In MS Access you can save that query and based on the saved query (I saved it as qryLoser) you can get your second result

```
SELECT qryLoser.Loser, Count(qryLoser.Loser) AS CountOfLoser
FROM qryLoser
GROUP BY qryLoser.Loser;
```

Comment: this is wrong -- what if winner does not equal team2?

Comment: According by the post and the example data either Team1 or Team2 is the winner. There is no draw foreseen and no matches still to be played.  To answer your question: Then Team1 is the winner. If you want to cover cases like no winner, draw etc. you need to add a second "inner" IIF statement.

Comment: I don't think it is clear what happens in the non-sql statement x or y as loser.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the original query -- as you an see I left some extra columns here (to make it clearer and you might want to use this for something else)?

```
SELECT Loser, COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT  MatchID, [Match Date], Tournamer, [Team 1], [Team 2], Winner,
    SWITCH([Team 1] = Winner,[Team 2],
           [Team 2] = Winner,[Team 1],
           true,'Unknown Loser') AS Loser
   FROM MatchesTbl 
) X
GROUP BY Loser
```

Here is the cleaned up answer:

```
SELECT Loser, COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT 
    SWITCH([Team 1] = Winner,[Team 2],
           [Team 2] = Winner,[Team 1],
           true,'Unknown Loser') AS Loser
   FROM MatchesTbl 
) X
GROUP BY Loser
```

*also note, that the answer to your first question in the inner query and the answer to the second question is the outer query*

Comment: This will not work in MS Access as CASE WHEN is not supported by MS Acccess.

Comment: @Storax -- good point, I switch to the switch syntax.